# Spring specify implementation in configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm writing application using spring mvc/boot, and I have two storage implementations: database storage and in memory storage. My global idea is choose in configuration file what storage application should use.

My idea is

- put @Qualifier annotation on each storage implementation
- create two configurations, like databaseStorageConfiguration and InMemoryStorageConfiguration
- depends on profile, apply first or second configuration

The thing is I don't know how to bind implementation and configuration.

I tried something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class InMemoryStorageConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("inMemoryStorage")
    private Storage storage;

    @Bean
    public Storage getStorage() {
        return storage;
    }
}
```

But I get an error, that 3 beans were found: 2 beans with dfferent implementation and the 3rd one - in config

#### UPDATE 1

I've added `@Profile("InMemory")` to Configuration and activated that profile in properties. That gave no changes but looks more logical now

#### UPDATE 2

Full configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class WidgetService {

    private WidgetCache widgetCache;

    @Autowired
    public WidgetService(WidgetCache widgetCache) {
        this.widgetCache = widgetCache;
    }
....
```

```
@Qualifier("databaseWidgetCache")
@Transactional
@Repository
public class DatabaseWidgetCache implements WidgetCache {

    private WidgetRepository widgetRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseWidgetCache(WidgetRepository widgetRepository) {
        this.widgetRepository = widgetRepository;
    }
```

```
@Qualifier("inMemoryWidgetCache")
@Repository
public class InMemoryWidgetCache implements WidgetCache {

    private WidgetLayersStorage widgetLayersStorage;

    @Autowired
    public InMemoryWidgetCache(WidgetLayersStorage widgetLayersStorage) {
        this.widgetLayersStorage = widgetLayersStorage;
    }
```

```
@Profile("InMemory")
@Configuration
public class InMemoryStorageConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("inMemoryWidgetCache")
    private WidgetCache widgetCache;

    @Bean
    public WidgetCache getWidgetCache() {
        return widgetCache;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
 Parameter 0 of constructor in
 com.widgets.service.widget.WidgetService required a single
 bean, but 3 were found:
    - inMemoryWidgetCache: defined in file [..../MemoryWidgetCache.class]
    - databaseWidgetCache: defined in file [..../DatabaseWidgetCache.class]
    - getWidgetCache: defined by method 'getWidgetCache' in class path resource
 [......../InMemoryStorageConfig.class]


 Action:

 Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
 to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
 that should be consumed
```

Comment: can you provide the other configuration and the stack trace of the exception

Comment: Why InMemoryStorageConfig has both injection and declaration of storage bean?

Comment: take a look here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html

Comment: your configuration is pretty messed up, please post your full configuration.

Comment: why you are annotating InMemoryWidgetCache and DatabaseWidgetCache with @Repository

Comment: @MaxExplode it has annotation because I want to autowire that classes. Its @ Repository, because it has a responsibility to store widgets

Comment: @MaxExplode and I dont want to manually create the instance InMemoryWidgetCache or DatabaseWidgetCache in configuration because they both has it's own dependencies in constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WidgetService should be changed to

```
    @Service
    public class WidgetService {

        private WidgetCache widgetCache;

        /** or 
        private List<WidgetCache> widgetCaches;
        public WidgetService(List<WidgetCache> widgetCaches) {
            this.widgetCaches = widgetCaches;
        }
        */
        public WidgetService(@Qualifier(<desired impl>) WidgetCache widgetCache) {
            this.widgetCache = widgetCache;
        }
    }
```

and need to annotate your `InMemoryWidgetCache` and `DatabaseWidgetCache` with `@Qualifier` annotation. since you are using default convention.

and please remove

```
    @Bean
    public WidgetCache getWidgetCache() {
        return widgetCache;
    }
```

i don't see a real use there

Comment: but can I do the same thing using specific configuration, and activate that configuration by activating specific profile?

Comment: put your profile in InMemoryWidgetCache or DatabaseWidgetCache

Comment: I get your point, but in configuration I want to specify not only implementation of Cache, but some another behaviour. For example, in DbConfiguration I want to move configuring dataSource bean, and entityManagerFactory because I dont need them when I use InMemoryStorage. And thats the reason why I want to use configuration

Comment: are you creating the data source programmatically or via an auto configuration

Comment: now I have it in spring-config.xml, but I want to move it to java config, in order not to create it when I use InMemoryStorage

Comment: Just exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration from @SpringBootApplication and create it manually with the profile.https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic and the entity manager also.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, and that solves my problem. But is it possible to choose what implementation should I use in Configuration, not in WidgetService itself?

Comment: I found the solution to what I wanted to do! Please see my answer. But you helped me a lot! Thank you

Comment: yeah it is possible, you can define a Conditional or ConditionalOnProperty

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify implementation in Configuration class, you don't need "Qualifier" annotation, and configuration should be changed to:

```
@Profile("inMemoryStorage")
@Import(InMemoryWidgetCache.class)
@Configuration
public class InMemoryStorageConfig {

}
```

thus, by activating profile, you choose the desire implementation